# Why I got an error if I named my controller as "leaves" in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The scaffold command is the following

```
ruby script\generate scaffold Leave employee_id:integer leave_type_id:integer date:date
```

I know I could change the name but I just wonder why it always throws `undifined new_leave_path`

Glad to know your brilliant thoughts.

Below is the full details of the error:

---

NameError in Leaves#index

Showing app/views/leaves/index.html.erb where line #26 raised:

```
undefined local variable or method `new_leave_path' for #<ActionView::Base:0x620ea70>
```

Extracted source (around line #26):

```
23: 
24: <br />
25: 
26: <%= link_to 'New leave', new_leave_path %>
```

Application trace:

```
app/views/leaves/index.html.erb:26
app/controllers/leaves_controller.rb:7:in `index'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
rake routes

new_leafe_path
```

or

```
map.resources :leaves, :singular => :leave
```

)

Answer (score 0):

@insic Hi

It is just working fine on my machine. may be there are some conflicts with any gem or plugin that you might be using. Can't explicitly find out what is the exact reason, as I am a newbie to rails.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
#routes.rb
map.resources :leaves
```

Comment: yes it is in place. the generate scaffold command automatically add it to routes.rb

Comment: Try running rake routes in terminal from the root directory of your application to check the route is being generated.